# Is there a way to get a Firebase Cloud Messaging Token in Unity if TokenReceived event is not fired?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to specific clients. At the start of the app, I initialize firebase using these 2 functions:

```
    public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
                Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
            }
        });
    }

    public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token)
    {
        DebugDisplay.Log("FIREBASE TOKEN RECEIVED");
        _token = token.Token;
        _isFirebaseInitialized = true;
    }
```

Most of the times, I get the token normally, but sometimes, the OnTokenReceived method is not called and there is no token.

I need to add a method to try to get the token again if the OnTokenReceived event handler hasn't been called after a few seconds. From what I have seen in the documentation, there isn't a method to get the token directly, the only thing to do is to listen for the TokenReceived event. I tried to unsubscribe and subscribe again to these events to no help. What am I supposed to do when this event doesn't happen?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/messaging/firebase-messaging#class_firebase_1_1_messaging_1_1_firebase_messaging_1a0cc2dfe98a6bc05ee5a7aad63f45a86b

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to Firebase support: https://firebase.google.com/support or filing an issue on the GitHub page (making sure you fill out all the template information): https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues . If it's failing sometimes, maybe it's a backend issue (support will help best) or an SDK issue (it would help if you could repro it in the sample app https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/messaging/testapp on the most recent SDK to start that process). I didn't see any obviously related bugs in a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Try FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync();

```
public void InitializeFirebase()
{
....
   GetTokenAsync();
}

private async void GetTokenAsync()
{
    var task = FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync();

    await task;

    if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
       Debug.Log("GET TOKEN ASYNC "+ task.Result);
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public void InitializeFirebase()
{
....
   StartCoroutine(GetTokenAsync());
}

private IEnumerator void GetTokenAsync()
{
    var task = FirebaseMessaging.GetTokenAsync();

    while(!task.IsCompleted)
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Debug.Log("GET TOKEN ASYNC "+ task.Result);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't exist  --